# WordPress: Filter content for certain string in links and change a element to span

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, str-replace

I’m using WordPress and I’d like to filter `the_content` for links that contain a specific string. If a link contains that string a certain class should be added to that element and the `a` element should be replaced by a `span` without any attributes.

Link pattern: `<a href="https://example.com/specific-string/file.pdf" title="Title">Link</a>`

Specific string: `specific-string`

If link contains specific string, output: `<span class="private">Link</span>`

So the WordPress filter I can use is the following:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'the_content_filter_links', 10, 1 ); 

function the_content_filter_links( $value ) {

    // 1. Find all links that contain the string `specific-string`
    // 2. Remove all attributes from `a` tag.
    // 3. Change opening and closing `a` tags to `span`.

    // Output the content
    return $value; 
};
```

I found [this](https://thisinterestsme.com/php-find-links-in-html/) to get all links in PHP but it makes use of of the `DOMDocument` class which I think cannot be used in my case?

Sidenote: I don’t want to use JS for that because I don’t like the user to see the link which would happen when he/she has JS disabled.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You should be able to use DOMDocument, did you try it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using DOM:

```
<?php

print_r(the_content_filter_links('<a href="https://example.com/specific-string/file.pdf" title="Title">Link</a>'));
print_r(the_content_filter_links('<a href="https://example.com/nonspecific-string/file.pdf" title="Title">Link</a>'));

function the_content_filter_links( $value ) {

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($value);
    // 1. Find all links that contain the string `specific-string`
    if (strpos($value, '/specific-string')) {
        // 2. Remove all attributes from `a` tag.    
        $link = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
        // 3. Change opening and closing `a` tags to `span`.
        $value = '<span href="'.$link->getAttribute('href').'">'.$link->nodeValue.'</span>';
        // Output the content
        return $value; 
    }
    return false;
};
```

Or a regex (DOM is better):

```
<?php

print_r(the_content_filter_links('<a href="https://example.com/specific-string/file.pdf" title="Title">Link</a>'));
print_r(the_content_filter_links('<a href="https://example.com/nonspecific-string/file.pdf" title="Title">Link</a>'));

function the_content_filter_links( $value ) {

    // 1. Find all links that contain the string `specific-string`
    if (strpos($value, '/specific-string')) {
        // 2. Remove all attributes from `a` tag.    
        preg_match('/.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*)<\/a>/', $value, $matches);
        if(count($matches) == 3) {
            // 3. Change opening and closing `a` tags to `span`.
            // Output the content
            return '<span href="'.$matches[1].'">'.$matches[1].'</span>';
        }
    }

    return false; 
};
```

Comment: Many thanks! I didn’t realize that I can load the html from `the_content` with `DOMDocument()`. That’s a great starting point, however if there’s more than one link and some other content it gets stripped out. But I think I can sort that out by myself. I keep you updated.